# How to setup metrics on camel-springboot non-web application

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-camel, spring-boot-actuator

I am running a kafka consumer application using `camel-spring-boot-starter`. The SpringBoot application implements `CommandLineRunner`. The below property is configured in my application.

```
camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true
```

I am trying to expose the springboot actuator metrics on the port 8080, but I am facing challenges in exposing the endpoint as it’s a non-web application.
The url http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics gives 404 status code.

How can I expose the actuator “/metrics” on an HTTP endpoint for my usecase?

Note: Actuator and camel-management dependencies are available in the classpath.

-Regards
Srikant Mantha

Comment: You should add an answer below rather than a comment

Answer (score 0):

My maven dependency had only spring-web, thought it would work. After adding spring-boot-starter-web dependency. It worked.
Closing this question